# Cannot stay logged in on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, firefox

I just switched my browser from Chrome to Firefox because I was having trouble using Chrome in our network and wanted to give Firefox a shot.

When using Chrome I could log into my Stack Overflow Account using Google and everything was fine.
Using Firefox however, I can log into this Meta site, other sites on the Stack Exchange (I tried Code Review) and stay logged in. 
Stay logged in as in I can post questions, write answer to posts, flag questions etc.

Now, on Stack Overflow I am always in a view that suggests that I am not logged in
---> I have a log in button on top, I cannot flag nor answer etc.
When I click on "Log in", I get a pop up "Welcome back, you are being redirected" and get back to where I started.

I went through Firefox' preference to check security and privacy settings but I think I might not get it any more open than it already is (which is I trust Stack Overflow now like my dearest aunt).

Do you or does anyone have an idea on where to look next, what the reason might be or if me and Firefox are simply not meant to be?

Yes, I checked this site and the vast plains of the internet first but could not find anyone having my problem. However, this might have been due to phrasing, so if I missed something very obvious please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the F5 key on the page with log in? It just seems like it is displaying a historical version of the page instead of a freshly loaded version of the page.

Comment: @ouflak: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I tried hitting the "reload" button in the browser as well as the key "F5". Both did not solve the problem.

Comment: Kill off all of your stack overflow cookies. I've no idea which one dies it, but when that happens, deleting all stack* cookies seems to work

Comment: @SeanCheshire: Thank you. That solved the problem.

Comment: @SeanCheshire, would you mind moving your comment into an answer? I'd do it, but the last time I tried that stunt here on meta, I got clobbered with downvotes. I'd think if the OP of the answer does it, all should be cool.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Moved to answer from comment:

Kill off all of your stack overflow cookies. I've no idea which one does it, but when that happens, deleting all stack* cookies seems to work

Comment: Specifically clearing StackOverflow cookies did the trick for me.