# Auto redirect bug happening on login

Tags: bug, login

I have not been able to access Stack Overflow for about a week now. I'm stuck in a loop that won't let me in.

1. I go to the login page
2. A notification pops up with "Welcome back [name]. You've been logged in. You are being redirected...
3. The page refreshes and I remain logged out.

Please assist.

Comment: what browser are you using? does it happen in other browsers? do you have any add-ons enabled?

Comment: What method do you use to login? If you are using OAuth, logout from your OAuth provider.

Comment: Uuuhhhh, how did you post this question then?

Comment: @rene, probably a separate account. Or at least I hope.

Comment: Doesn't look like it....

Comment: I've only got one account. I'm logged in using another computer. The machine in question is a Mac running Firefox. I've tried Firefox on this machine and it works fine.

Comment: Your other box is malwared up?

Comment: No. not at all Martin.

Comment: or: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251681/cannot-stay-logged-in-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

I have also this problem. I partially solved by purging the cookies.

This problem arouse today after I switched from chrome to firefox; the switch imported also the chrome cookies, perhaps they confuse the stack exchange sites as they are sent from firefox.

BTW: I was recognized only on meta...