# "Not logged in" when arriving from search engines, but after a refresh, I am

Tags: support, login

A few weeks ago, I cleared all my cookies and offline data in Firefox. Ever since, I have a situation where I appear as not logged in when I click a link to Stack Overflow from Google. I found [this Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251681/cannot-stay-logged-in-on-stack-overflow), which is very similar, but its answer does not to help in my case (on the contrary, it seems to have introduced the issue).

So it usually goes like this:

- I search for something in Google
- I click a result, which leads me to a Stack Overflow Question
- I want to upvote something, but can't because I'm not logged in.
- I click 'Log in' at the top right, and it just brings me to my profile page, now logged in.
- Even if in the previous step I would simply refresh the exact same page, I will be logged in!

So somehow, if I arrived from Google, Stack Overflow does not want to show me as logged in. Why? Can I avoid this issue in any way?

I use Firefox 77 on Windows 10 (with Adblock Plus and Bitdefender).

---

I did a few more tests to see which "referring sites" cause issues.

- Google
- DuckDuckGo
- Bing
- Baidu

But the following works fine:

- Yahoo
- Most other websites I could find

Comment: Noticed this in FF on mobile somewhat frequently, and periodically in FF on Linux. No idea what triggers it, and it's definitely hard to reproduce, but something is definitely borked.

Comment: But after you logged in once, you stay logged in? Or does this happen everytime a new tab is opened?

Comment: You do accept third-party cookies? Or at least whitelisted the SE domains. Any userscripts/plugins running? Which OS?

Comment: It's only the "landing pages", i.e. where I end up on from Google, that shows me as "not logged in". If I type in the URL myself, I'm logged in. If I click a link from inside SO, I'm logged in. But if I click a link from Google, I appear not logged in, until I click any other link or refresh.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 77 on Windows 10 (update 2004).

Comment: I do use "Bitdefender Antivirus Plus". I also have Firefox Tracking Protection and Adblock Plus, but ruled those out by turning them off. Bitdefender is complicated to figure out, but I turned off everything I could think of, but still got the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the issue after testing various things... Bitdefender was the issue, but not the app itself, rather the Extension it had installed in Firefox. After disabling that one ("Bitdefender anti-tracker"), the issue went away.

Comment: Same problem here. It's annoying..

Comment: If this corrected your issue, could you mark this as an answer? That way people will know that you found a solution. Thanks.